# require_once(...) can't find file but it's definitely there

Tags: php

I am trying to include a file in a PHP script using a relative path. However, the function returns an error stating that the file doesn't exist.

It *does* exist - I have attached a file structure screenshot too - and other pages can include it without issue.

### Code

```
require_once("../config.php");
```

### Output

> Warning: require_once(../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/sites/c84/7de/example.com/web/inc/sections.php on line 25
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /www/sites/c84/7de/example.com/web/inc/sections.php on line 25
>
> ### File Structure Screenshot

[image: File Structure Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/www/sites/c84/7de/example.com/web/inc../config.php
```

requires a `/` after `inc` and before `..`

```
/www/sites/c84/7de/example.com/web/inc/../config.php
```

so something like

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../config.php');
```

Comment: Thanks - using `__DIR__ . '/` solved the issue. Any idea why it wasn't finding the file with just `/../` or `../`?

Comment: `/../` would be an absolute path, going up a level from root (technically impossible).

Comment: `"config.php"` and `"/config.php"` would prob work as well.

Comment: But what about `../`? Neither `config.php` nor `/config.php` worked.

Comment: `../` is appending to the entries in the include path, which doesn't have trailing `/` on the folders, so it's effectively looking for folders with names ending in `..`

Comment: A `/` as the first character of your path to include treats it as an absolute reference, so always from root folder and ignoring the include_path entries

Comment: So why did `/config.php` not work, when `config.php` is in the root folder?

Comment: A leading `/` refers to the __filesystem__ root, not to the web root

Comment: I see. Thank you @MarkBaker